# Start multiple threads with Tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a basic tcp server:

1. Server should be able to broadcast a stream of messages to all of the connected clients
2. Server should be able to receive commands from all clients and process them

This is what I've got in my `main` function:

```
let (server_tx, server_rx) = mpsc::unbounded();
let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Shared::new(server_tx)));

let addr = "127.0.0.1:6142".parse().unwrap();

let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).unwrap();

let server = listener.incoming().for_each(move |socket| {
    // Spawn a task to process the connection
    process(socket, state.clone());
    Ok(())
}).map_err(|err| {
    println!("accept error = {:?}", err);
});

println!("server running on localhost:6142");

let _messages = server_rx.for_each(|_| {
    // process messages here
    Ok(())
}).map_err(|err| {
    println!("message error = {:?}", err);
});

tokio::run(server);
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=35297de9bb6fb6c398d443684bf932c6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

I'm using the `chat.rs` example from tokio repository as a base.
I'm sending data to `server_tx` on incoming tcp messages.
What I have trouble with is consuming them.
I'm "consuming" incoming message stream using `server_rx.for_each(|_| {`, now, how do I tell tokio to run it?

`tokio::run` accepts a single future, but I have 2 (and possibly more). How do I combine them so they run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joins the futures together:

```
let messages = server_rx.for_each(|_| {
    println!("Message broadcasted");
    Ok(())
}).map_err(|err| {
    println!("accept error = {:?}", err);
});

tokio::run(server.join(messages).map(|_| ()));
```

The `map()` combinator is needed because [`Join`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/struct.Join.html) `Item` associated type is a tuple `((), ())` and
`tokio::run()` consume a future task that require a `Future::Item` of type `()`